# terminal -php artisan commands does not work properly

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-artisan

I am trying to learn larvel framework. When I try to use a php artisan command in teminal it does something unusual. It prints 'k' word with the command and than executes it.

> ➜  project git:(master) ✗ php artisan serv
>
> kLaravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000
>
> ➜  project git:(master) ✗ php artisan clear
>
> kThe compiled services file has been removed.

and when I open my local server same weird 'k' letter shows up again.[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

my parent view is(layout.blade.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
    @yield('footer')
</body>
</html>
```

and welcome page:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
    <h1>The csdfadfda Goes Here</h1>
@stop
```

I don't know where the hell this 'k' comes from and i have no idea how to fix it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What coding program are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write a "k" character to your index.php or routes.php or any always parsed file before `<?`. Find and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You are probally printing it in an ServiceProvider or in an Controller.

Try to find in your project something like that:

```
echo 'k'
```

or

```
echo "k"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using K on the very first line on here:
[image: Your Coding Image]

Remove k from the very first line.